# Laravel and backbone web application - var app undefined?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, laravel

I am working on a web applicaiton that interacts with a RESTful api. The client is built in the laravel and backbone, what I am struggling to do is come up with an intelligent way to load in the correct, models, collections and view based on the current URL.

I have a blade template that gives me universal branding, and then are templates for each of the sections of the site, that load in appropriate underscore templates, scripts, data etc.

For example the users page is accessed at `http://domain.local/users` and this loads in the following scripts,

User.Collection.js

```
(function( Users, app_arg ){

    'use strict';

    Users.Collection = app.UserCollection

}(POPS.module('users'), POPS ));
```

User.Model.js

```
    (function( Users, app ) {

    'use strict';

        Users.Model = Backbone.Model.extend({

        });

    })(POPS.module('users', POPS));
```

User.Views.Master.js

```
    (function( Users, app_arg ) {

    'use strict';

    Users.Views.Master = Backbone.View.extend({

        el: '#app',

        template: _.template( $('#tpl-user').html() ),

        events: {
            "click .js-add-new-user" : "launchModal",

        },

        initialize: function() {
            this.listenTo( this.collection, 'reset', this.render );
            this.listenTo( this.collection, 'add', this.render );

            // app.dashProjectCollection = this.collection;
        },

        render: function() {

            this.$el.html( this.template() );

            new app.UsersView({ collection: this.collection });
            new app.userModal({ model: app.User, collection: this.collection });
            //this.filterView = new Dashboard.Views.Filter();
            //this.projectView = new Dashboard.Views.Projects({ collection: this.collection });
            //this.CollaboratorView = new Dashboard.Views.Collaborators();


            return this;
        },

        launchModal: function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $("#newUser").modal();
        }

    });

}( POPS.module('users'), POPS ));
```

Everything gets fired from app.js

```
// Main object for the entire app
window.POPS = {

    config: {
        api: {
            base:'http://pops.local/api/v1/',
        }
    },

    // Create this closure to contain the cached modules
    module: function() {
        // Internal module cache.
        var modules = {};
        // Create a new module reference scaffold or load an
        // existing module.
        return function(name) {
            // If this module has already been created, return it.
            if(modules[name]) {
                return modules[name];
            }
            // Create a module and save it under this name
            modules[name] = { Views: {} };
            return modules[name];
        };
    }(),

    init: function() {

        // :: app start :: //
        var app = POPS;
        var Module = app.module( $( '#popsapp' ).data('route') );

        // Creates a Master object in the global namespace so data can be passed in from the DOM.
        // This would be replaced with a master Router if we weren't using actual pages
        app.Initialiser = function( initialCollection ) {
            this.start = function() {

                //don't cache ajax calls
                $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });


                if(Module.Collection !== undefined) {
                    this.collection = new Module.Collection();
                    this.view = new Module.Views.Master({ collection: this.collection });
                } else {
                    this.view = new Module.Views.Master();  
                }

                if(this.collection !== undefined) {
                    this.collection.reset( initialCollection );
                }

                //moved this here so script runs after the DOM has loaded.
                //but script.js still needs completely removing.
            };
        }; 
    }
};

// Entry point into the application
POPS.init();
```

I cannot fathom why app is undefined!

Answer (score 0):

in your first block you have

```
(function( Users, app_arg ){

    'use strict';

    Users.Collection = app.UserCollection

}(POPS.module('users'), POPS ));
```

you define app_arg in the function arguments but use app.UserCollection within the function. app here will be undefined.

This would also be the same for User.Views.Master.js

Comment: Thanks is there a better way to start the backbone side, than I am currently doing?

Comment: hmmm, not ever used backbone in this type of setup as i will use it to create a single page app and so my setup is to use require.js to do all my module loading as i hit different routes in my app but i suppose that's what your blade templates are doing for you. What i can say is the setup here looks well organised in terms of keeping everything modular, the only pain I can see is if the js code is locked into the blade templates would you have to copy code if you want it in two different templates?

Comment: The only repetition of code, is calling javascript files in templates, I think I am going to move the templates out in the main parent template, so all backbone files have all templates available to them

Comment: hi if this answer fixed your problem btw can you mark it as answered or provide some more information on what answer you are looking for, cheers